# Correct letter in asterisk is accepted. But a correct letter + another letter, also accepted

Tags: java

Example in the Guess game St_i_g Mani_ulat_ _n

When I guess the letter "r" for (St "r" ing) which is correct
But when I put r+NJDFSAD23 still correct

```java
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String word = "String Manipulation";
    StringBuilder secretPhrase = new StringBuilder("St*i*g Mani*u*at**n");
    int position;

    System.out.println("Guess each letter from the (*) of the Secret Phrase");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
      position = secretPhrase.indexOf("*");

      if (position == -1)
        break;

      System.out.println("Guess the letter: " + secretPhrase + " : ");
      char ch = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);

      if (ch == word.charAt(position)) {
        secretPhrase.replace(position, position + 1, word.substring(position, position + 1));
        System.out.println("Correct guess! " + secretPhrase);
      } else {
        System.out.println("Letter is not in the phrase. Try again");
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Congratulations, you have guessed the Secret Phase.");
  }
}
```

Comment: JAVA != JavaScript

Comment: You will have to add a check, that the line you read via `scan.nextLine()` actually only contains one character, before extracting the `charAt(0)`.

Comment: Do I need to set limit?